# How to find max date with mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a 'users' collection, and each user holds a field called 'birthday' which is a javascript Date object.

I wish to query the 'users' collection using mongoose in order to find the oldest user in the collection. How do I do that?

Comment: But `db.users.find().sort({ "birthday": -1 }).limit(1)` is the correct answer and not the accepted answer there. It is was the highest voted answer says though. Index the "birthday" field for the best performance.

Comment: Wanting to find the oldest user requires the _minimum_ date, not the max date as the title suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mongoose code in your js file.

```
var dummyDate = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
Users.find({"birthday": {$lte: dummyDate} }, function(err, result){
        result.forEach(function(instance, indexx,record){
        var bday = record[indexx].birthday;
        if(moment(dummyDate).isBefore(bday)) {
            dummyDate = bday;
        } else if(moment(dummyDate).isBefore(bday) {
            dummyDate = bday;
        }
    });
});
```

Please modify the code according to your convenience.
dummyDate will give you the oldest date at the end of the forEach. You can use moment to work with the dates in mongoose.